# Installing Oracle XE in CentOS 6.5

Tags: installation, centos6.5, oraclexe

Is it possible to Install Oracle XE in CentOS 6.5?

If yes, is there a guide for dummies out there how to install XE in CentOS 6.5, without using Virtual Machine such as VirtualBox.

Thanks for any response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can just download the zip/rpm from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html

Then run:

```
unzip oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
cd Disk1
rpm -ihv oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

That should do it.

Comment: Nothing special, just install the rpm, that's it.